# using document.writeln() for a particular DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var Jstr = { "JSON" : [ 

      { "Eid"  : 102,"Ename":"", "Ecode" : "<input type ='text'/>", "Eprops": {"name": "", "value":"", "maxlength":""}}

   ] 
   } ;

   $(".search").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;

    for(var i =0;i<Jstr.JSON.length;i++)
    {   
        var obj = Jstr.JSON[i] ; 
        if(obj.Eid == id)
        {
              document.getElementById('down').innerHTML=document.writeln(obj.Ecode);
        }
    }
});
});
```

Here I'm using JSON object to create a input type = text tag by clicking a button on the page. Then I'm trying to create that tag in a particular div. My main focus is to create the input tag in a "DIV" of id "down" using document.writeln() method. ".search" is the class of the button which is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please don't ever use `document.write` unless you really really know what you're doing. There are possible scenarios when that method makes sense, but they are quite rare in the real world.

Second, if you're employing jQuery - well, you can use jQuery for this particular task as well. ) Compare this line...

```
document.getElementById('down').innerHTML = obj.Ecode;
```

... with this:

```
$('#down').html(obj.Ecode);
```

That's if you want to completely rewrite the contents of `<div id="down">` each time. If what you actually want is just to add a new element, use `.append`:

```
$('#down').append(obj.Ecode);
```

... or, if you want to add those properties stored in `Eprops`:

```
$('#down').append($(obj.Ecode, obj.Eprops));
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your kind help.
Sir I've one more query that using prompt box for taking input for the properties would be appropriate or not??

Comment: Yes, why not? Again, there are alternatives: you can create a so called modal window with your own code and show `<textarea>` element within it. That's more flexible, but quite complicated. )

Comment: actually i wanted to take inputs for the properties in the Eprops which i was thinking to take from the popup box like prompt but the javascript in the page donot function when prompt is used. Is there any alternate method in jquery????

Answer (score 1):

I think u want to do something like this and is better to use jsfidle for ur problem [sol1](http://jsfiddle.net/XX2Gs/1/)

```
     var tempId = document.getElementById('down');
     tempId.innerHTML=obj.Ecode;
```

and [sol2](http://jsfiddle.net/XX2Gs/2/)

```
     $('#down').append(obj.Ecode);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 document.getElementById('down').innerHTML=obj.Ecode;
```